# c++ Detecting If A User Entered A String Instead Of An Int

Tags: c++, string, int

I am making a program where the user must choose an option by entering 1,2 or 3. I am able to detect what number they enter and get the program to repeat the prompt if they enter a number other than these with the use of a switch statement. Every time I enter a letter the program constantly repeats the prompt hundreds of times per second. How can I check the variable to ensure it contains an int before proceeding. I have a feeling it would involve using a string then checking it to ensure it contains an int then converting it, if I could have an example of this code it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Check the result of the input operation.

Comment: you could store only the first character and check if the ascii value is a digit if you're only doing 1-3 as valid input

Comment: It will be practically impossible for us to help you definitively unless you post the code you're using.

Comment: You may just need a `default` case in your `switch` statement. It would be easier to help were you to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 9):

You should **always** verify that you successfully read the desired input. If the input failed, you probably want to get rid of the offending character and retry:

```
int value(0);
while (!(std::cin >> value)) {
    std::cout << "you entered a non-digit character\n";
    std::cin.clear();   // make sure that std::cin is happy to do something
    std::cin.ignore();  // ignore the offending character
}
```

When input fails, the `std::ios_base::failbit` is set on the stream and the stream won't convert to `true` (or the not operator `!` applied to a stream returns `true`). Once the `std::ios_base::failbit` is set, the stream will refuse to make any progress until the bit is cleared again. Using `clear()` you can reset the error bits. Once the bits are reset the offending character is still in the input, however. To get rid of the next character you can just use `ignore()`. If you feel you want to ignore the entire line of input, you'd use something like

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```